# Issue extending Array in IE8

Tags: javascript, arrays, internet-explorer-8

So IE8 doesn't support `Array.indexOf()`, so I copied some code that extends the Array prototype so that it is supported and it works.

```
if (!Array.prototype.indexOf) {
    Array.prototype.indexOf = function (elt /*, from*/) {
        var len = this.length >>> 0;

        var from = Number(arguments[1]) || 0;
        from = (from < 0)
             ? Math.ceil(from)
             : Math.floor(from);
        if (from < 0)
            from += len;

        for (; from < len; from++) {
            if (from in this &&
                this[from] === elt)
                return from;
        }
        return -1;
    };
}
```

However, I'm running into an issue when I iterate over an array now.  Take this for example:

```
arrayObject = [];
//do some stuff
for(var i in arrayObject) {
  ...
}
```

The problem is that after extending the Array prototype, one of the values for `i` above is now equal to `indexOf`, and the value at that index (i.e. `arrayObj[i]`) is equal to the contents of the function.  This happens even when the length of the array is zero!! So even when the array is empty, it's still iterating once through for the `indexOf` entry.

I realize that I can simply do some type checking in the loop, but I'd rather not do that because I'm retrofitting fallback compatibility onto a large existing project. Is there a way to have the `indexOf` array functionality in IE8 without running into this issue?

Comment: Don't do that.  Use a regular for loop.

Comment: Yea, that would work, except I'm retrofitting this onto a large project so going back and changing all of the array code is painful.  It also wouldn't suffice for the associative arrays (hacked dictionaries) that some of the code uses.

Comment: Associative arrays should be objects, not arrays.

Comment: What I mean is arrayObj["Hello"] = "World";

Comment: That should be an object, not an array.

Comment: You can still iterate through it using for(var i in array) isntead of having to use a filter

Comment: @SLaks Oh, I understand what you mean.  You're saying it's not a true array if you're using it like `array["Hello"]` because that's the same thing as `array.Hello`.  You're right of course

Comment: Just FYI - in case you wrote this yourself from scratch, you can get this and many polyfills from MDN: [Array.prototype.indexOf() Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#Polyfill)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use hasOwnProperty to make sure that the i is an index of the array and not a function like indexOf.

```
for (var i in arrayObject) {
  if( arrayObject.hasOwnProperty( i ) ) {
    //...
  } 
}
```

See docs below for more info:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

That said I'd probably recommend using a counter e.g.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayObject.length; i++) {}
```

or an each method from a framework like underscore, dojo or jquery etc.. than using a for..in loop like this.

Answer (score 2):

If at all, you have to use only `for..in` to iterate the array, just check if the current item is defined in the Array object, with `Object.hasOwnProperty`, like this

```
var arrayObject = [];

for(var i in arrayObject) {
    if (arrayObject.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      ...
    }
}
```

**Note:** As per [MSDN's documentation of `hasOwnProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/328kyd6z(v=vs.94).aspx**), it is supported in Internet Explorer 8 Standards mode.

---

The proper way to define `indexOf` would be to make in non-enumerable, like this

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'indexOf', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function polyFillIndexOf() {...}
});
```

Since we defined it as non-enumerable, `for..in` loop, will not pick the `indexOf` property. So, you can still use `for..in` with the Array objects (though it is not recommended to do so).

But unfortunately, as per [MSDN's documentation of `Object.defineProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd548687%28v=vs.94%29.aspx), it works only with DOM objects in IE-8.

---

Apart from this, when you use `for..in` with an Array, you might run in to this [inconsistent order of keys problem mentioned in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in),

> Array indexes are just enumerable properties with integer names and are otherwise identical to general Object properties. There is no guarantee that `for...in` will return the indexes in any particular order and it will return all enumerable properties, including those with non–integer names and those that are inherited.
>
> Because the order of iteration is implementation dependent, iterating over an array may not visit elements in a consistent order. Therefore it is better to use a for loop with a numeric index (or `Array.prototype.forEach()` or the `for...of` loop) when iterating over arrays where the order of access is important.

---

So, the simplest and the best way to do this would be, using simple `for` loop, with numeric array indexes, like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrayObject.length; i++) {
    console.log(arrayObject[i]);
}
```

or using [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ff679980%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) (which is also supported in Internet Explorer 8 Standards mode), like this

```
arrayObject.forEach(function(currentItem) {
    ...
});
```

---

**PS:** Be careful with

```
arrayObject = [];
```

you are actually creating a global variable called `arrayObject`. You might want to use the `var` keyword, like this

```
var arrayObject = [];
```

Comment: yea, I was just showing an example.  I know better than to scope globally

Comment: @jugg1es Cool then :-) Most of us miss that during the coding and review phase, and since the code works fine, we will discover it only when we face weird issues.